# How to exclude more div id's from clicking event

Tags: jquery, events, mouseup

I am new to jquery, and i like to know if there is a way to exclude multiple div's from clicking event.
First, i was looking how to hide certain div, when mouse clicks outside of it. 
This is only solution that gave some result (:not selector didn't work).
I would like to exclude #cartbasket div as well, so that same button can continue to toggle up and down #cartbasketList ul below.
I tried many combinations, but without any good..

html:

```
<div id="cartinfos">
  <div id="cartbasket"></div>
    <ul id="cartbasketList">
      <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">somelink</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cartinfos {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}

#cartbasket {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#cartbasketList {
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
   border-top: 5px solid #ff0000;
   width: 250px;
   height: 400px;
   top: 60px;
   right: 0px;
   background:#fff;
   z-index: 999999;
}
```

jquery:

```
  $(function() {

      $("#cartbasket").click(function() {
         $("#cartbasketList").slideToggle("fast");
    });


      $("body").mouseup(function(event) {
        if (event.target.id != 'cartbasketList') {
            $("#cartbasketList").slideUp(100);
        }

    });


    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do again?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to target the elements you want, instead of starting with all the element (they all bubble to body) and then excluding ?

Comment: `$("body").mouseup()` is called for *every single element on the page*.  That is really extreme, and under normal circumstances is unusable.  Since you haven't described *what* you want to happen, it's extremely difficult to correct the the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should track what your click event and check to see if a certain element has been clicked.

Be sure to only use 1 click event otherwise the events will start to bubble and give you an undesirable affect.

```
$(function() {

    var $cartList = $('#cartbasketList');

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        var target = e.target.id;

        if(target == "cartbasket"){
            $cartList.slideToggle('fast');
        }
        else {
            $cartList.slideUp('fast');
        }
    });

});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/VcYr2/)

Comment: Thanks for quick response Adjit, this is working well. I'll keep your advice in mind.

Comment: @gundra glad to hear it. If this is working you should mark it as correct. But also, my advice with regards to 1 click event... I meant 1 click event for THIS. You can delegate other elements to click events, they just wont pass your conditional

Comment: Sorry Adjit , this is my first post here :)  .  I did a bit of modification, on code that you just have sent to me. I add *** else if (target == "cartbasketList") { $cartList.stop();*** So now #cartbasketList don't disappear when click on it. That was what i wanted on first place.  I learned something today, thank you very much !!!

Comment: @gundra very cool! also, if you want the animation to reset when you call `.stop()` call `.stop(true, true)`